# Installing a project in KDevelop fails

Tags: kdevelop

I've got a project in KDevelop, but attempting to install if from within the IDE simply gives the following output:

```
/home/<myusername>/Projects/rect/build/release> kdesu -t -- make -j8 install
*** Failed ***
```

However, when I run the exact same command from the exact same location in terminal (outside KDevelop), it asks for the root password as it should and installs just fine. All possible solutions for the problem I could find are either for missing kdesu or kdesu installed in a location not on `PATH` by default; however, I most certainly have kdesu on my system and I have exported its location, and like I said, the exact command that KDevelop appears to be trying to run works beautifully outside the IDE.

So, how would I get the install option working in KDevelop itself?

I'm using Debian Wheezy if this matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the problem with my `PATH` was that I was only setting it in the console but the `PATH` is different for GUI applications (thanks D.J.Duff for pointing that out, can't believe I didn't know this) - I fixed it by adding `PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/kde4/libexec"` (the location of these binaries) to my `.profile` file [as suggested here.](https://superuser.com/questions/121261/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-graphical-login-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by creating a symlink to the kdesu binary in `/usr/local/bin`, which seems to be working just fine. I'm still curious as to why it didn't work before since the directory containing kdesu was on the `PATH`, though.

Comment: Do you run kdevelop from the command line in a shell with the variables set? If not there is maybe a different PATH in the visual shell to what there is in the command line shell and you either need to run kdevelop from the command line or set up the path in your visual shell (since the visual shell doesn't usually read files like .bashrc and has its own way of setting up variables). Just a thought.

Comment: Note that you can actually configure KDevelop to run the `make  install` step as root.
Just right-click on the Project, select `Open Configuration` and then switch to the `Make` tab.